# JasperListener? Upgrading from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

Since Tomcat 8.0 has reached end of life, I want to upgrade my application directly to Tomcat 9.

When I deploy my Java based App from local to my server, I have a script which overrides the server.xml. I upgraded the server to a tomcat 9 and tried to put my application in there, but I get an error when trying to start it.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

Tomcat 9 does not know JasperListener. I googled this issue and found the "Jasper How to" page from apache, but I do not get it. Is Jasper now installed without me having to insert the JasperListener in the server.xml? And do I have to update anything else when upgrading from Tomcat 8 to 9?

Comment: Don't use a Tomcat's server.xml for another major version.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I have a server.xml in my project and a script that overrides the tomcat's server.xml when deploying. I am trying to figure out what I need to change in that server.xml. I commented out the JasperListener and it worked, but now I do not know if Jasper is still working. Thus my question if I simply don't need the JasperListener anymore and what else I need to change.
Edit: Also when deploying my project, I set a new Tomcat with every deployment, pulling the tomcat per script and installing it on the server. So I need to override the server.xml

Comment: It's not possible to answer, overriding by another version being a bad practice. server.xml can be changed : a little/very much/not at all. The most important to check are the port attributes.

Answer (score 32):

`org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener` is no longer required.  So if it exists in your `server.xml` - comment it out!